# NASM Segmentation Fault at Return

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am creating a program that accepts a two-digit number then prints the prime numbers from 1 to the two-digit number. After I've printed all of the prime numbers, when the program is already exiting, a seg fault shows up. How to fix this? Thank you in advance.

Here are the subroutines that will provide the prime numbers.

```
;firstLoopBody, this will loop the numbers from 1 to N
;secondLoopBody, this will loop the numbers to be divided from the firstLoopBody
getPrimes:
    mov ebp,esp
    call firstLoopBody

    ret 6

firstLoopBody:
    ;loop the numbers from 1 to N
    mov ax,[ebp+6]
    cmp ax,[ebp+8]
    jne next

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,exitString
    mov edx,esLen
    int 80h

    ret

next:
    inc word[ebp+6] ;add 1 to the firstLoop
    mov word[ebp+4],1 ;restart the value of secondLoop every getPrimes

secondLoopBody:
    inc word[ebp+4]
    ;check if the secondLoop == firstLoop
    mov ax,[ebp+6]
    cmp ax,[ebp+4]
    je printOne

    mov dx,0
    mov ax,[ebp+6]
    div word[ebp+4]

    cmp dx,0 ;compare the remainder to 0

    jne secondLoopBody ;if the remainder is not zero, loop again
    jmp firstLoopBody ;if equal, go back to the start

printOne:
    call printPrimes;print prime. if the loop has reached its end without breaking, it means that there are no divisible numbers found for the number, therefore making it a prime number
    jmp firstLoopBody

printPrimes:
    sub esp,4 ;to allocate for the characters to be printed
    ;convert to characters
    mov dx,0
    mov ax,[ebp+6]
    mov cx,10
    div cx

    mov [ebp-4],ax
    mov [ebp-2],dx ;-2 = ones, -4 = tens

    add word[ebp-4],30h
    add word[ebp-2],30h

    ;printing
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,prime
    mov edx,primeLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    lea ecx,[ebp-4]
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    lea ecx,[ebp-2]
    mov edx,1
    int 80h

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,nl
    mov edx,nlLen
    int 80h

    add esp,4

    ret
```

Comment: The segfault will have an associated backtrace of some sort. Use the tools you have at your disposal to capture and inspect the backtrace. I'm sure you can run in some sort of stepping or debug mode as well? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What calling convention is getprimes suppose to be? How do you call it. The `ret 6` seems suspect. That was the first thing I saw in the code so am commenting. Stepping through in a debugger would tell you where things fail. Running it in a debugger and getting a backtrace as jdv mentions would probably clue you into the problem as well.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't build a 64-bit executable?  `add esp, 4` would truncate your stack pointer.  But Michael is right: if `getprimes` is ever called, you're screwed.  Besides the `ret 6`, it clobbers its caller's `ebp` value.  Anyway, learn to use a debugger.  Update your question with details (like register values and extact segfault location) from a debugger.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.

Comment: From `int 0x80` usage it doesn't look like 64b code, so verifying that this is compiled as 32b binary is good idea. Rest of the problems can be resolved by using debugger. At first I would be watching `ebp/esp` and relevant "stack" memory content ... and everything else too. :D